# Binding time of free variables of quoted terms in Scheme

Tags: binding, scheme, eval, quote, free-variable

I try to understand how works the quote phenomenon in Scheme. In particular, I would like to understand when are bound free variables of quoted terms.

For instance, when I write

```
(define q 'a)
(define a 42)
(eval q)
```

it returns 42. Thus I deduce that binding time is at runtime. But in this case, why does this code fail

```
(let ((q 'a))
  (let ((a 42))
    (eval q)
  )
)
```

and returns

```
unbound variable:  a
```

Can someone explain me what is the binding time model of quoted terms (is is comparable to MetaOCaml for instance? (I don't think so)) and the difference between define and let?

Comment: what implementation? "typing" where -- at the REPL, in a file?

Answer (score 2):

Scheme has lexical scope discipline, not a dynamic binding discipline.

Your top-level `define` definitions behave as though creating a binding in a top-level lexical environment.

The second code snippet actually creates two lexical environments, one nested inside the other. So where (*not "when"*) `q` is bound, `a` is still unbound. But the real question is, which environment is used by `eval`?

Your implementation behaves as though it uses the definitional environment, or a top level environment, but certainly not the current lexical environment, for evaluating the *symbol* `'a`, which is the value of the `q` variable. The *variable* `q` has a clear binding lexical environment, created by its `let` form -- but where does a *symbol* `'a`'s binding reside? How are we to know?

Details should be in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First off a quoted symbol is just as much a variable as a string with the same sequences of chars as a variable in a C syntax language like Javascript. They have nothing in common since they live in different worlds.

`eval` does not know of lexical variables, only global ones. It knows of lexical variables that is in the structure to be evaluated. Eg.

```
(eval '(let ((tmp (list q q))) 
          tmp))
```

`q` needs to be global, but `tmp` is a lexical variable.

Standard Scheme, aka R6RS, take a second argument where you can choose what libraries should be available. These are still considered global.

Variables are bound at runtime. Implementations are free to optimize and constant fold as long as this optimization does not break the report.

`eval` is a powerful procedure which should never be used unless it's the most sensible way to solve a problem. I've seen it twice in production code during my 17 year career and I think it's one time too much.